# Calling viewwillappear after dismissing modalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can I call `viewwillappear` after dismissing `modalviewcontroller`?

Any idea please because after dismissing my `viewwillappear` didn't get called :

presenting my viewcontroller modally : 
//firsviewcontroller :

```
-(IBAction)AddActivity:(id)sender{


    CreateActivity *addViewController = [[CreateActivity alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateActivity" bundle:nil];

    addViewController.delegate = self;
    addViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    addViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:addViewController animated:YES];


    addViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 260, 680, 624);

}
```

//secondvioewcontroller : I create An alertview to dismiss this modalview , but the viewwillapear didn't get called:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){


        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]){
            [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        else {
            [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain? How are you checking? In my experience, viewWillAppear always fires for the presenting view controller when the presented modal is dismissed.

Comment: I have editing my post to see what I did , What I am missing ?

Comment: @OuassimMouyarden You need to learn how to think about OOP properly before you go right into things. That being said, I'll still help you, for now. What do you want to happen exactly when a button on your UIAlertView is pressed?

Comment: I want to dissmiss my modalview , and call viewwillappear of my firstviewcontroller to do some manipulation

Comment: The code worked for me, and viewDidAppear was called. Did the modal view controller get dismissed?

Comment: Yes It's dissmidded, I talking about viewwillappear

Comment: Sorry, missed that, but viewWillAppear was called as well. Are you talking about viewWillAppear in the presenting view controller?

Comment: viewwillappear of my firstviewcontroller

Comment: It won't be called on an iPad. It definitely should be called on an iPhone.

Comment: why it won't be called on an iPad !

Comment: what the problem with my code ?

Comment: Is this for iPad or iPhone? Why are you doing: addViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 260, 680, 624)? A view controller's view doesn't have a superview, so that line won't do anything.

Comment: Ok, there's nothing wrong with your code -- viewWillAppear isn't called for an iPad, because the view never disappears when you present the modal as a form sheet. IT will be called if you present it full scale.

Answer (score 13):

`presentModalViewController:animated:` / `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` are deprecated.  Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` / `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` instead.

You can use the completion block to execute any code post dismisal:

```
- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        MyCustomViewController* mcvc = (MyCustomViewController*)self.presentingViewController;

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: ^{

             // call your completion method:
             [mcvc someCustomDoneMethod];
        }];
    }
}
```

Better yet, if you're using a storyboard then you can implement an unwind segue and trigger your completion code in the unwind callback method.

Comment: thank you for reply, so  [self.presentingViewController someCustomDoneMethod];the someCustomDoneMethod must be defined in my firstviewcontroller , it will be called after dismissing the modalview??

Comment: yes.  you'll likely have to cast the presentingViewController into your custom controller type so that you can call the method.  Note I'm making one edit to the sample.  You don't have to call dismissViewControllerAnimated on the presenting view controller.  You can just call it against self.

Answer (score 12):

Since you're presenting the **modal view controller** as a **form sheet**, the presenting controller's view never disappears, so `viewWillAppear:` is not called after the dismissal. If you want the presenting view controller to handle something after the dismissal, call a delegate method in the modal controller's `viewDidDisappear:` method. You've already set the delegate, so I presume you already have a delegate protocol in `CreateActivity`.

By the way, you should use the non-deprecated methods to present and dismiss your modal view controller.

Comment: instead of calling a delegate method you can execute code in the completion: for dismissViewController:animated:completion:.  Placing the code in viewDidDisappear may have issues if the controller is part of a nav stack (e.g you push another controller..)  If you still want to use viewDidDisappear, be sure to check self.isBeingDismissed.